# Show that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}y_\epsilon(x)=\delta(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, analysis

For $y_\epsilon(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}(e^{-\frac{x}{\epsilon}}-e^{-\frac{2-x}{\epsilon}}),\ x\in[0,1]$ prove it converges to Dirac's delta as ${\epsilon\rightarrow0}$.
Answer:
It is sufficient to prove $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^x y_\epsilon(u)\phi(u)\,du=\phi(0)$, for any $\phi\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$.
The $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^x y_\epsilon(u)\, du=1$, after some calculations. Therefore I can take $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^x y_\epsilon[\phi(x)-\phi(0)]\,dx$.
But can I use continuity? How can I know that $\lvert x-0\rvert<\delta$?

Second Thought:
Since $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^x y_\epsilon(u)\, du=1$, change variables as $z=\frac{u}{\epsilon}$ and $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_0^{x/\epsilon}y_\epsilon(z\epsilon)\ dz=\int_0^{x/\epsilon}y_\epsilon(0)\ dz=1$.
Then use Dominated Convergence:
$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_0^{x/\epsilon}y_\epsilon(z\epsilon)\phi(ze)\ dz=\int_0^{x/\epsilon}y_\epsilon(0)\phi(0)\ dz=\phi(0)$

Comment: you are on the right track. One can also use nothing but Calculus (the man value theorem and integration by parts) to get the result. You should however integrate up to $1$ for $y_\varepsilon$ is supported in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz sure, I tried using before  the mean value theorem and failed, so I appreciate your answer very much, I prefer it this way! Also, I understood about integration up to 1, after seeing your answer!!

Comment: As you can see from my solution, yhe MVT appears when you one estimates $|\phi(\varepsilon x)-\phi(0)|=|\phi'(\xi_{\varepsilon,x})|\,|\varepsilon x|\leq \|\phi'\|_u\varepsilon x$. Then one has to do intergratin by parts (which is a little tedious). But the advantage is that you can also het some idea of how fast things are converging. you lose that if one applies directly dominated convergence.

Comment: @OliverDiaz yep, I saw the MVT. Again, thank you, it was a very explanatory answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  change of variables you suggest along the mean value theorem and some integration by parts:

$$
y_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\Big(e^{-x\varepsilon^{-1}}-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^{x\varepsilon^{-1}}\Big)\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$$

For any $\phi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\int_\mathbb{R} y_{\varepsilon}(x)\phi(x)&=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\int^{\varepsilon^{-1}}_{0}(e^{-u}-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^u\big)\phi(\varepsilon u)\,du\\
&=\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\Big(\int^{\varepsilon^{-1}}_{0}(e^{-u}-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^u\big)\big(\phi(\varepsilon u)-\phi(0)\Big)\,du \\
&\quad +\phi(0)\int^{\varepsilon^{-1}}_{0}e^{-u}-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^u\,du\Big)
\end{align}

The term
$$
\frac{1}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\phi(0)\int^{\varepsilon^{-1}}_{0}e^{-u}-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^u\,du=\phi(0)\frac{\big(1-e^{-\varepsilon^{--1}}\big)^2}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}\phi(0)
$$

The term
\begin{align}
\frac{\int^{\varepsilon^{-1}}_{0}(e^{-u}-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^u\big)\big(\phi(\varepsilon u)-\phi(0)\Big)\,du}{1-e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}}&\leq \frac{\|\phi'\|_\infty\varepsilon}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\int^{\varepsilon^{-1}}_0u\big(e^{-u}+e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}e^u\big)\,du\\
&=\frac{\|\phi'\|_\infty\varepsilon}{1-e^{-\frac{2}{\epsilon}}}\Big(1-\varepsilon^{-1}e^{-\varepsilon^{-1}}-e^{-\varepsilon^{-1}}\\
&\quad\quad+ \varepsilon^{-1}e^{-\varepsilon^{-1}}-e^{-\varepsilon^{-1}}+e^{-2\varepsilon^{-1}}\Big)
\Big)
\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0+}0
\end{align}